# Play a game from external cd-drive

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, external-drive, cd-drive

Since the internal cd-drive of my computer is broken, I purchased an external one. I was able to install a game with this external drive, but when I want to start the game with the exact same drive, nothing happens. Neither do I get a fault message or any other pop up.

Could this be due to the fact that the cd-drive is external and thus connected via USB? How can I make this work?

More detailed information: the game in question is Black & White 2, installed on a Windows Vista machine, but in the settings I told it to run in compatibility-mode (Windows XP SP 2).

Comment: Is it using the same drive letter as when it was installed?

Comment: I did not remove the drive after installation, or put it in another USB drive. I did have to restart to complete the installation, but I don't think the letter of the drive changed.

Comment: Have you reason this game on this machine before in the past?

Comment: No, I have not installed the game on this machine before.